# Creating packet and getting acknowledgment using java

Tags: java, sockets, gps, packet

Hi I am getting the Data from the GPS device, I want to send the response back to the Gps device by creating the packet my packet is like this.And once I sent this packet I want to check whether the packet is delivered or not.

```
No. Field   TYPE    Length  description
1   sMark    Char   6      Flag of message (\r\n*KW\0)
2   packetLe short  2      Message Length
3   CMD     Short   2          0x8200
4   cErrorCodeChar  1      0x00OK, 0x01invalid deviceID
5   sEnd     Char   2      message end "\r\n"
```

I have Created the packet like below and i am sending the packet to the gps device but I am not getting any responses or acknowledgment back.

```
try {
               StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytearrypacket = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dateoutputpacket = new DataOutputStream(bytearrypacket);
    dateoutputpacket.writeBytes("\r\n*KW\0");
    dateoutputpacket.writeShort(0x4400);
    dateoutputpacket.writeShort(0x0200);
    dateoutputpacket.writeBytes("*KW,NR09G05618,015,080756,#");
    dateoutputpacket.writeBytes("\r\n");
   dateoutputpacket.flush();
    byte[] res = bytearrypacket.toByteArray();
 for (byte b : res) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02X ", b));
   }
                DatagramPacket responsepacket = new DatagramPacket(res, res.length, packet.getSocketAddress());
                dsocket.send(responsepacket);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalBlockingModeException il) {
                il.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ilg) {
                ilg.printStackTrace();
            }
```

**Updated**

**Actually Hex format wht i suppose to get:**

```
   0d 0a 2a 4b 57 00   //head of the message
        44 00               //length of the message =0x0044
        02 00               //command ID=0x0002
        00 00 00 00         // IP of client software
        00 00               // port client software
        2a 4b 57 2c 4e 52 30 39 47 30 30 30 30 31 __ 2c 30 31 35 2c 30 38 30 37 35 
        36 2c 23 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 __ 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
        00 00 00 00 00 00 //command string 50byte(*KW,NR09G00001,015,080756,#)

        0d 0a //end of the message
```

**BUt I am getting**

```
0D 0A 2A 4B 57 00 44 00 00 02 2A 4B 57 2C 4E 52 30 39 47 30 35 36 33 37 2C 30 31 35 2C 30 38 30 37 35 36 2C 23 0D 0A
```

Comment: you are using `datagram sockets` and there is no acknowledgement sent for `UDP` packets as i understand.

Comment: Ok. whether my packet creation is correct?

Comment: What's the question? What happened when you ran the code? Why are you asking the same question again?

Comment: I run that but I am not getting the response back

Comment: I If u don't mind do know about c++.

Comment: 0d 0a 2a 4b 57 00   //head of the message
44 00               //length of the message =0x0044
02 00               //command ID=0x0002
00 00 00 00         // IP of client software
00 00               // port client software
2a 4b 57 2c 4e 52 30 39 47 30 30 30 30 31 __ 2c 30 31 35 2c 30 38 30 37 35 
36 2c 23 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 __ 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 //command string 50byte(*KW,NR09G00001,015,080756,#)

0d 0a //end of the message  I need to generate the packet like this.

Comment: Hi i have update my answer please look at that

Comment: @EJp please help me in this.

Comment: Help you in what? You seem to be creating the message correctly according to your definition, and sending it. Maybe your message definition is faulty. I don't see what C++ has to do with it.

Comment: Hi updated my answer please look at that.

Comment: Since your writing binary data to the device, do you know that your using the correct endian (big vs little)?  Are you getting the correct number of bytes back?