# Converting byte array to jpg image file throughing exception

Tags: java, file-io, arrays, jpeg

Hi I have a byte array that I am converting to jpg image but that is giving exception as below please explain me wht is the problem with this.

```
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(someByteArray);
                Iterator<?> readers = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("jpg");

            //ImageIO is a class containing static methods for locating ImageReaders
                //and ImageWriters, and performing simple encoding and decoding. 
                ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) readers.next();
                Object source = bis;
                ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(source);
                reader.setInput(iis, true);
                ImageReadParam param = reader.getDefaultReadParam();

                BufferedImage image = reader.read(0, param);
            //got an image file

                BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            //bufferedImage is the RenderedImage to be written

                Graphics2D g2 = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
                g2.drawImage(image, null, null);

                File imageFile = new File("D:\\newrose2.jpg");
                ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", imageFile);
```

Exception:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Invalid JPEG file structure: SOS before SOF
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readImageHeader(Native Method)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readNativeHeader(JPEGImageReader.java:550)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readNativeHeader(JPEGImageReader.java:550)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.checkTablesOnly(JPEGImageReader.java:295)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.gotoImage(JPEGImageReader.java:427)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readHeader(JPEGImageReader.java:543)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(JPEGImageReader.java:986)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(JPEGImageReader.java:966)
    at Trnsport.writejpegfile(Trnsport.java:398)
    at Trnsport.getData(Trnsport.java:107)
    at Trnsport.run(Trnsport.java:63)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Edit:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("image" + new Date().getTime() + ".jpg");
fos.write(someByteArray);
    fos.close();
```

Comment: The message is clear: The image file is malformed. Also, all that setup code is horribly convoluted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your byte array already contains valid JPEG data, you do not need to invoke the JPEG reader or writer -- you can write the bytes to the file using ordinary file I/O.

If the byte array actually contains some format of raw pixel data, you will need to load it into a BufferedImage directly (such as via [`setRGB`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB-int-int-int-)) and encode that as a JPEG.

The fact that you're getting an exception trying to decode it implies it is not JPEG data, but raw pixel data. Or, perhaps it is a different type of image altogether, or it has an image at some offset into the array instead of at the start the array, or it is not an image at all.

Comment: Hi I am trying like that also but I am not getting please see my updated code.

Comment: @user3511026 The question is, what format of data is in the byte array?

Comment: that is sending from the gps device that continuance image data only.

Comment: @user3511026 So.. what's in it?

Comment: That's  has image data shell i send that file can u just tell me where to upload the file here i will upload please.

Comment: hi i have uploaded the file please check.

Comment: please check this like.

Comment: @user3511026 Okay, that is a JPEG; I can see the JFIF header. But the data is either invalid or incomplete, which is why it can't be decoded or opened.

Comment: Wht is that JFIF  please and How u are saying that data is invalide please.

Comment: @user3511026 JFIF = JPEG File Interchange Format. It *is* data for a JPEG file. But no program will open it. Notice that the last 443 bytes are all zeros; the data is clearly broken somehow.

Comment: The byte array i took 5000 byte that should be exact of the image leangth.

Comment: where to see the JFIF  in my data.

Comment: @user3511026 In your array the first four bytes are FFD8FFE0, which indicates a JPEG file. Two bytes after that you can see the ASCII character codes for the letters "JFIF": 74, 70, 73, 70. This won't help you though. The point is that the data is broken, so you need to fix the code that reads or generates it.

Comment: Can i have your skype id please.

Comment: @user3511026 Near the top of your file is some data that looks like this: `$.' ",#(7),01444`. I'm not 100% certain but I don't think that belongs in the JPEG file, but it does resemble some syntax in the packet format you were trying to generate in [one of your previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23333975/creating-packet-and-getting-acknowledgment-using-java). Perhaps the bug is that you are not decoding the packets sent by the GPS device correctly. I've helped you all I can. Good luck.

Comment: Thank u so much I got the output.